# Writing linked structure into class

Tags: c++, class, structure

I have a program read in a txt file and prints out all the lines in the file. 
I used a linked structure to do that.
code:

```
#include <string>
struct ListNode{
std::string item;
int count;
ListNode* link;
};

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(){
char filename[] = "src/inputdata";
std::cout << " Reading from file: " << filename << " . . . ";

std::ifstream in( filename );
if (in.fail()){
    std::cout << " ... not able to read it! Exiting." << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
std::cout << " ... OK, file opened." << std::endl << std::endl;

ListNode* first = new ListNode();
ListNode* p = first;
int count = 1;

while (!in.eof()){

       getline( in, p->item );

       p->count = count++;

       p->link = new ListNode();

       p = p->link;
}

count = 1;

p = first;

   while (count <= p->count)

   {

   p->count = count++;

   std::cout << p->count << ": " << p->item << std::endl;

   p = p->link;

   }
       }
```

requirement is to convert this program into 3 files, driver, main cpp file and header file. I am quite new to c++. I have set up the header file as follows, but I guess I miss something in it, maybe getter and setter...

Header file:

```
//ListNode.h
#ifndef LISTNODE_H_
#define LISTNODE_H_
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

class ListNode{
public:
ListNode();
virtual ~MyData();

private:
string item;
int count;
ListNode* link;
};
#endif /* LISTNODE_H_ */
```

What should I do with the other two files? 
Appreciate your answers. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Now as you using class..

Create a method in Class

```
class ListNode
{
....
        ListNode* CreateList();
....
};
```

which does the operation of reading the file and creating the list; same what you are doing in `main()`

include `ListNode.h` file in `ListNode.cpp` and provide the definition to the method you have declared in `ListNode` class

Cpp file

```
#include "ListNode.h"
.... //remaining code
```

Finally in third file `main.cpp`. include "ListNode.h"

```
#include"ListNode.h"
...//code..
```

In main method create object of `ListNode` class and do the operation you want to do

Comment: what should I do in the createlist() ?

Comment: Do it in the same way you are doing in `main()`; `return head pointer`... :-).. give it a try .. if you need help comment..

Answer (score 0):

The header file (.h):

```
//ListNode.h
#ifndef LISTNODE_H_
#define LISTNODE_H_
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class ListNode {
    public:
       ListNode();
       ~ListNode();

       // Accessor functions.
       string const& getItem() const;
       int getCount() const;
       ListNode* getLink() const;

       // Modifier functions.
       void setItem(string const& i);
       void setCount(int c);
       void setLink(ListNode* l);

    private:
       string item;
       int count;
       ListNode* link;
};
#endif /* LISTNODE_H_ */
```

The implementation file (.cc):

```
// ListNode.cc
#include "ListNode.h"

ListNode::ListNode() : count(0), link(NULL) {}

ListNode::~ListNode() {}

string const& ListNode::getItem() const
{
   return item;
}

int ListNode::getCount() const
{
   return count;
}

ListNode* ListNode::getLink() const
{
   return link;
}

void ListNode::setItem(string const& i)
{
   item = i;
}

void ListNode::setCount(int c)
{
   count = c;
}

void ListNode::setLink(ListNode* l)
{
   link = l;
}
```

main.cc:

```
// main.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "ListNode.h"

int main()
{
   char filename[] = "src/inputdata";
   std::cout << " Reading from file: " << filename << " . . . ";

   std::ifstream in( filename );
   if (in.fail()){
       std::cout << " ... not able to read it! Exiting." << std::endl;
       return -1;
   }
   std::cout << " ... OK, file opened." << std::endl << std::endl;

   ListNode* first = new ListNode();
   ListNode* p = first;
   int count = 1;

   while (!in.eof()){

       string item;
       getline( in, item );
       p->setItem(item);
       p->setCount(count++);

       p->setLink(new ListNode());

       p = p->getLink();
   }

   count = 1;

   p = first;

   while (count <= p->getCount())

   {
      p->setCount(count++);

      std::cout << p->getCount() << ": " << p->getItem() << std::endl;

      p = p->getLink();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you:) I have try it for 6 hrs.... I missed the getter method and tried to access the data directly... No wonder it was not working